# GTM | Tracking a button that is not a link

Tags: triggers, google-tag-manager

I am setting up a new trigger in GTM and I am having trouble tracking it.  Normally I would check everything using the GTM debug window/console.

When I have this open and click on the button I wish to track nothing appears.

I am trying to track a button, not a link.

The button is:

```
<button id="trigger-onlineSizer" class="btn btn-default">Find your size</button>
```

However when I click on other links they are tracked, for example this link does show and is trackable.

```
<nav class="button-bar">
  <a href="#" id="btn--bodyheight" class="button button--next-screen">
    Next
  </a>
</nav>
```

In GTM I have made sure that I have enabled, under the  Variables config all items below, Pages, Utilities, Clicks and Forms.

Any guidance on how to track such a button in GTM would be much appreciated,

Thanks,

Comment: Could you please share your trigger settings? What class, id, or element attribute are you trying to use for filtering the trigger?

Comment: Hi @kgrg , there's 2 parts to this answer, I will list the trigger settings - lower down. More important (I think) is when in preview mode, I see nothing registering in the Summary list when I click on the button.  

In this list I can see when I click on other elements, that are not being tracked, however it only displays on certain elements. As the click is not registered in preview mode I am struggling to debug.

To answer your original question the trigger settinsg I have tried are to use either Click - all elements, or just links. I then tried to filter with HTML ID and also Click ID.

Comment: Is there a chance, that the button or any of its parents are disabled? This can be a reason for GTM (and generally the browser) to ignore a click on the element.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @kgrg, how do you mean the button being disabled?

I have also tried to use the Element Visibility trigger, as the click I want to track surfaces the pop-up. So if it will track an element that is only in the pop-up this could also work.

Tried using element ID = screen__form--bodyheight